# Downloading a directory/subdirectory from the FTP server to ios application folder

Tags: ios, ftp, download, directory, synchronization

i am creating an application which requires me to download & sync all the data on the FTP directory to the ios application's document directory. I found many examples like  apple's sample FTP code : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

FTPhelper class :

https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C13-Networking/15-FTP%20Helper

& some others as well. But No one is suitable to download & sync all the data from server to my document directory. I am able to download the files one by one but How to download a complete directory ? Is there any way for this?

I found the library for chilkat here : 
http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatftp.asp

I tested it to synchronise the folder & it works successfully. But it is paid $149 . Cost is very high. Is there any other alternative for this? Or any other way by which i can achieve the same?

I found some other questions on this site but they haven't provided a proper solution. 
Please show me the correct direction. Even if i have to write code myself for the sync then please tell me how i should do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create exact same directory tree on your device and dowload each file using queue.

Comment: For each directory i can receive sub-directories  only upto 1 level.Then for each i have to call recursive function.But i can have a single FTP server call at a time.But my directory on server might have n sub-levels.This wil be very time consuming if i call them one by one.I already tried this by FTPHelper class.Other way i was thinking is call all the FTP in multiple threads in background.But In that case how can i recognise that which response is for which FTP call. But chilkatsoft.com is doing it in good way.I don't know how they are doing it.Kindly suggest more ways to achieve that.